# Drupal CiviCRM Menu not full length (shoreditch and otherwise)

Tags: drupal, menu, shoreditch, global-menu

I upgraded three sites today.

Site 1 - Already had Civi 5.6 - updated to Drupal 7.60 and Shoreditch (SD) Alpha26. Result: CiviCRM menu is not full length.

Site 2: Updated from SD 25 to 26 - and to Drupal 7.60 - No issues - Was civi 5.3, upgraded to 5.6 - Result: Civi menu is not full length.

Site 3: Updated to Civi 5.6 and SD 26 - Wordpress site - no issues.

I do not think this is a Shoreditch issue, rather there is a menu issue between Civi 5.6 & Drupal 7.6.

Could this be related to [this Drupal 8 change?](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12463)

[image: Desktop Width]
[image: Mobile Width]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't directly related to the Drupal 8 change but instead is related to a change to the `civicrm-drupal7.js` file.

The JS is forcing the CiviCRM menu to 97% width - to allow for the Drupal admin toolbar's shortcut bar toggle element. It doesn't however account for sites which don't use the core toolbar module or styling or sites which don't use the toggle element.

A fix for this issue has been committed to CiviCRM ([located here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12937/commits/b7ce19c794a6511c51c34c58fe34937e945602cb)) and should be merged in to 5.8 at the latest.

The [release summary](https://github.com/civicrm/release-management/blob/master/README.md) documentation is worth reading and provides a high level overview of how releases are managed and what kinds of changes are (generally) included/accepted at which stages.

Comment: Supplementary question: how do we know what version (5.6.1, 5.7, 5.8...) this fix will arrive? Semantic versioning would have it in 5.6.1 but it seems like we aren't really doing patch releases often?

Comment: So patch releases are generally for important security fixes or regressions (I'm not sure this is considered either) - so I'd doubt that a 5.6.1 release would be issued for this.

5.7 should be "locked" at this point as the RC is cut at the same time as the current stable. 

5.8 is the next RC which will be 'cut' when 5.7 goes stable. The general rule is that the stuff for 5.8 will be what's ready when 5.7 is released.

Comment: Just as feedback for the process. This menu glitch makes Civi look like an unpolished/incomplete software. For now - I am patching but maybe it should be considered for patch releases..

Comment: Understood themak, & thanks for the feedback! Yep - ideally that's what patch releases are for, and I think it's a resource question whether CiviCRM has capacity to release a patch for backwards-compatible bugfixes of this nature.